# PYTHON and OANDA API

Tags: python, api

I am using the Spyder IDE to run and test my code. I am pretty much finished with the coding. However, when I run it, the following comes up:

```
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:843: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
{
    "code" : 1,
    "message" : "Invalid or malformed argument: accountId",
    "moreInfo" : "http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/docs\/v1\/troubleshooting\/#errors"
}
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the information provided in the [link](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings)?

Making unverified HTTPS requests is strongly discouraged, however, if you understand the risks and wish to disable these warnings, you can use disable_warnings():

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Alternatively you can capture the warnings with the standard logging module:

```
>>> logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

Finally, you can suppress the warnings at the interpreter level by setting the PYTHONWARNINGS environment variable or by using the -W flag.